# Correct way to create CMap of VARIANTs

Tags: c++, dictionary, com, mfc, variant

I need to create a dictionary collection of [VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)s using [CMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s897094z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class. My dictionary is defined as such:

```
CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, CComVariant, CComVariant> map;
```

I then add elements as such:

```
void setKeyValue(CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, CComVariant, CComVariant>& map, CString& strKey, VARIANT& varValue)
{
    map.SetAt(strKey, varValue);
}
```

Can someone check if this is the proper way of populating CMap with VARIANTs? I haven't done COM for a while so I want to make sure that I'm not causing any memory leaks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work and is correct.

Important is the use of a CComVariant or _variant_t type that supports correct copying and destruction of Variants.

But why don't you use std::map

Comment: Idk. I was in the MFC "world" so I went with CMap. Can I ask a follow-up question? Say, if I declare the map as such: `CMap<CString, LPCTSTR, CComVariant, CComVariant&>` it still compiles, but what is the difference?

Comment: There is in fact no difference. But I feel more comfortable with the std::map classes and features. Even when in the MFC-world there is never a problem to use the STL-world. Never!

Comment: STL does look out of place in an MFC application, so using the MFC collections is probably the best way to go.